# Why does this popular author convert all images to .jpg?

Tags: php, image, jpeg

The code below is modified from an O'Reilly Book - Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript which can be found [here](http://www.lpmj.net)

Why are all image types converted to .jpg?

Does .jpg offer the best quality/size ratio?

```
  public static function upload()
    {    
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $path1="i8.jpg";
    $path2="z_p/$email.jpg";
    $path3="i9.jpg";     
    $path4="z_p/$email-1.jpg";     
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['ufile']['tmp_name'], $path2))
      {
      $typeok=TRUE;
      switch($_FILES['ufile']['type'])
        {
        case "image/gif":   
          $src = imagecreatefromgif($path2); 
          break;
        case "image/jpeg":  
        case "image/pjpeg": 
          $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($path2); 
          break;
        case "image/png":   
          $src = imagecreatefrompng($path2); 
          break;
        default:            
          $typeok = FALSE; 
          break;
        }  
      if($typeok)
        {
        list($w, $h) = getimagesize($path2);

        $tw  = $w;
        $th  = $h;

        /*Run 1*/

        $max = 50;
        if($w > $h && $max < $w)
          {
          $th = $max / $w * $h; 
          $tw = $max;
          }  
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
          {
          $tw = $max / $h * $w; 
          $th = $max;
          } 
        elseif ($max < $w)
          {
          $tw = $th = $max;
          } 
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);           
        imagejpeg($dst, $path2);
        imagedestroy($dst); 

        /* Rune 2 */

        $max = 20;
        if($w > $h && $max < $w)    
          {
          $th = $max / $w * $h; 
          $tw = $max;
          }  
        elseif ($h > $w && $max < $h)
          {
          $tw = $max / $h * $w;     
          $th = $max;
          } 
        elseif ($max < $w)
          {
          $tw = $th = $max;
          }
        $dst = imagecreatetruecolor($tw, $th);
        imagecopyresampled($dst, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $tw, $th, $w, $h);       
        imagejpeg($dst, $path4);
        imagedestroy($dst);
        imagedestroy($src);
        }
      }
    else
      {
      copy($path1, $path2);
      copy($path3, $path4);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are lots of nasty surprises you can hide inside a jpeg file (or any of a number of image formats). By always recreating an image this way, you gain a certain amount of confidence that the image your server issues is sanitized.

Comment: Hmm... the EXIF data would be the most obvious start; there have been some infamous thumbnail leaks where the main picture was cropped to cut off sensitive information, but the thumbnail was still entire. I'm sure I've heard of more insidious things to can attach to or interweave into JPEGs (e.g. use it to transfer secret data via your profile image, etc.) Search the web, I'm sure you'll find more ideas!

Answer (score 2):

JPEG doesn't always offer the best size/quality ratio, It depends on the image content, if it has many colors with many gradients, or is scenery picture, JPEG may be the best option, but for something like screenshots PNG will offer the best size/quality ratio.